# Why don't my devices have power after separating one room's wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m rewiring an upstairs room so it is separate from the other three rooms and found two wires which are both black and separated from each other. One is hot and the other is not. After tracing it into the attic it looks like the hot was connected to black and neutral to white. After I separated it from the room and hooked it back up none of the light or outlets are working in the whole upstairs. The wire is showing hot when I put my power detector next to it.
[image: two wires][image]
Here are some pictures that will hopefully help describe what I did. I may end up just running another separate line for the two other rooms up there but this is what I have going on[image]

[image]

**update 1/14 8:30pm**
So I did not mention that the only thing I left connected to everything in room 1 was the light in the ceiling but I took the fixture out until I finished the room. For kicks I figured I’d hook the old fixture up and low and behold all of the lights now work, but they are dim and flicker.

Comment: Something in your post doesn't make sense because you said you are separating this room from other rooms, but you havent explained how. You would need another live circuit properly rated and wired to do what it is you are suggesting. What you've pictured isnt that. It's concerning you traced the wire to the attic but dont know where it is going. Can you provide any before modification pictures, and draw out the circuts so we know what connects where? You need this information as well. Isolate power and test/trace it all out.

Comment: I ran all new wire for this room, haven’t hooked it up yet. I’m more concerned with the other two rooms that the lights aren’t turning on. I’m asking about the existing wiring that won’t work anymore. I removed all old wiring to this room. The top picture of two wires is what is coming up from the basement that the power is coming from, the bottom picture is where the two wires went to that I pulled out and am no longer using. I connected the two wires to the main supply line in the attic that goes to the two other rooms but they are not working. Hope that makes a little more sense

Comment: Maybe these aren't the wires you think they are.   With them hooked up and a load plugged into the powered sockets, does the other wire still read "not hot"?

Comment: I might be tracking in my head what the issue could be but unless you can tell us a detailed before and after we'd just be guiding you to guesswork. You really need a before and after identifying all the changes you made. Obviously a change you made has rendered it not working and if you hadn't traced the A--B--C--D.......Z endpoints of the circuit, then your hot is.... somewhere, and your neutral is ..... somewhere... each circuit connecting to it should be HOT-HOT and not miswired. The fact that it is not working is telling us you detached a hot AND/OR neutral from the live circuit.

Comment: Do you have a tone tool? You can find them at the big box stores. You really MUST identify the panels hot, and panels neutral start point in the building, then trace it point to point and label it as you go so you know what to connect where.

Comment: Please take photos in the box that you disconnected where pink meets blue & orange. Also, do you have ground wire at the location you can use to test your presumed neutral return to panel? Since you believe you know the hot, SECURE PANEL BREAKERS. USE TEST LIGHT to ensure no HOT is present. Then ensure all light switches are OFF, everything is unplugged (Everything). if power is safe, then test ground to each wire at the location, the TRUE NEUTRAL should read nearly 0 ohms if you have a good ground. Once identified, decide if it goes to the wire you think it goes to.

Comment: There was no box, it was all just tied up and electrical taped. I installed a new box where it meets in the attic. The house was built in 1901. There is no ground wire, only the two wires. I will try to get more pictures tonight

Comment: If wiring is old, your case is probably a 'shared neutral' between  various circuits. Alòso remember that color-coding wasn't used at that time. My advice is to call an electrician to have it fixed

Answer (score 0):

You may have a 'borrowed-something' (not unusual in old wiring) so you have 2 phases or two neutrals at each place.

My advice is to "invert" the two blacks (you have previously disconnected and reconected).